# Hit Back button 3 times to go back to Main Activity

Tags: android, search, android-intent, back

I have a main activity that I can initiate a search to searchable activity. I can also initiate a search in my search activity. So my launch mode for the searchable activity is singleTop.

If I do my search in **main activity**, I can go back to the main activity from searachable activity by clicking the back button **once**. Now the problem is after the first search in main activity, if I do another search in my **searchable activity**, I need to click the back button **three times** to get back to the main activity. I am not sure what I miss in my codes.

**Android Manifest**

```
    <activity 
        android:name=".SearchableActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data 
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
    </activity>
```

**Searchable Activity**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_listview);
    getListView().setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.lblNoResults));
    db = new StoreDB(SearchableActivity.this);

    onPostExecute();
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_listview);
    getListView().setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.lblNoResults));
    db = new StoreDB(SearchableActivity.this);

    onPostExecute();
    setIntent(intent);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    super.onDestroy();
    db.close();
}
```

I have the onDestroy in searchable activity. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I meet the same problem, have you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because, you are not finishing the SearchableActivity while going back to MainActivity.

Override `onBackPressed` method in `SearchableActivity` as:

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        finish();
    }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I added this to my searchable activity but I still need to hit the Back button three times.

Comment: The `Activity` should be finished when the back button is pressed anyway. So, unless there is extra work being done in `finish()` this shouldn't be necessary

Answer (score 0):

You can add the flag [FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT) to start your `SearchActivity`. This will bring that `Activity` to the front if there is already an instance of it so you don't have to keep backing through the other instances.

Also, probably not related to your problem but why do you have

```
onPostExecute();
```

in `onCreate()`? Is this your own method or the method of `AsyncTask`? If it is in `AsyncTask` then you shouldn't be doing this. According to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

> Do not call onPreExecute(), onPostExecute(Result), doInBackground(Params...), onProgressUpdate(Progress...) manually.

You should let it be called when `doInBackground()` is finished

Comment: That's not the issue. When I hit the Back button, it doesn't go to other instances. It just won't go back to the main activity until I hit the button the third time...

Comment: onPostExecute is my own method to do the search.

Comment: Are you sure, have you tried it? If you are calling `SearchActivity` from the same `Activity` then it will create a new instance...unless I don't understand what you are doing

Comment: Ok, I would suggest changing the name so it isn't confusing. I don't think its good practice to use a function name that is part of the Android framework already, but that's just my opinion

Comment: OK, I have something to add here. After I do my search in searchable activity, the focus is on the search term. So the first time I hit back button, the focus goes to the action bar. The second time I hit the back button, the focus disappears. So when I hit the back button the third time only it goes back to the main activity.

Comment: OK, I didn't know it's used by Android framework. I will change it.

Comment: Ok, that helps some. I don't use the native `ActionBar` so I don't know but can you call `setFocusable(false)` on it?

Answer (score 0):

try this code....

you override **onBackPressed()** method with **super.onBackPressed()**.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}
```

It is for detecting default back pressed by super.onBackPressed().
so, after pressed back button your **current Activity** will be finish using **finish()**.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19557715/306719), I have met the same problem, and at last I found this solution accidentally. I am not sure if it work for you but you can have a try.