# BACK key show the different behavior

Tags: android

I am trying to learn Android by imitating some existed apps.

I choose Google Map for Android with version 5.x because Gapps comply to the Android style.

And I am trying to implement this feature:

User search something through the Search Widget in the ActionBar, then every item of the result will displayed at the map as a marker, at the same time, the `MenuItems` inside the ActionBar will be changed.

I made it working, however I found that the `BACK` key works differently between the Google Map and my Example app.

See this [GIF](http://imgbin.org/images/15449.gif) to make it clear.

As is shown, user only need press the `BACK` once to go back to the Home page of Google map application, and leave the application by pressing once again.

However, in my application, user have to press the `BACK` twice to go back to the Home page of my app, and what's more, the new added menu item(TO RESULT LIST) is not removed.

At first, I think that Google map may capture the `BACK` press event, and do some job.

However, even I tried to capture the `BACK` press event, I can not implement the same effect.

This is my [Activity code](http://goo.gl/2rtzDz) and the [AndroidManifest.xml](http://goo.gl/c92Kth)

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I am the poster of this post, and it seems that I have got a solution for my problem(accidentally):

After your search, set the `searchView` to be no focusing use this:

```
searchView.clearFocus();
```

Then you will find that user only need to hit the `BACK` key once to get back to the Homepage of the application.

I am not sure why but it do solve my problem.